# CRM WEB API v9.2 Update OpportunityProducts: Trying to update EquipmentId in OpportunityProducts Entity and getting error

Tags: javascript, api, dynamics-crm, crm

CRM do not support direct update of Entity Reference properties, Use Navigation properties instead.

Trying to update  EquipmentId in OpportunityProducts Entity and getting the error.

How to get the Navigation properties?

Comment: can you write the code that you tried to update the records?

Comment: Header:
Request URL: https://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/opportunityproducts(968f0a1d-0f8b-ec11-93b0-0022482e437c)
Request Method: PATCH
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: ---------
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Payload:
{quantity: 4, lineitemnumber: 1, description: "",…}
xxxxxx_bundletotalcost: 34.24
xxxxxx_totaldiscountamount: 0
xxxxxx_totalexpcost: 0
xxxxxx_totalmaterialscost: 34.24
xxxxxx_totalprofcost: 0
description: ""
extendedamount: 0
lineitemnumber: 1
quantity: 4
_xxxxxx_trainer_value: "25620f3b-25a3-e911-a95d-000d3a4f1a4f"

Comment: when dealing with lookups (like the trainer one in your code) the syntax is different, try to use my tool Dataverse REST Builder to generate the right syntax https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB

Comment: It helped me to figure out thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when dealing with lookups (like the trainer one in your code) the syntax is different, try to use my tool Dataverse REST Builder to generate the right syntax github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB

this tool helped me to get the solution